# Perl: using () when calling a method that doesnt need argument

Tags: perl

Generally speaking, what's the difference between?

```
my $call = Module->new();
```

and

```
my $call = Module->new;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, the first one is two characters longer. Specifically speaking, too.

They're different ways to write the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

They are functionally identical.

However, I've taken to using the optional parentheses when calling a method that does an action, and not using them when it's returning a property.

```
my $n = $foo->n_elements;
$foo->populate_table();
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a valid one in case there is a run-time search of the elements of the object based on the presence or absence of the parenthesis. Consider the case, if there is no (), then the assumption is that that particular element is a variable and when there is (), then we are searching for a function. But no such distinction exists at run-time. all the elements are stored and whether you use () or not, all the elements are scanned. Hence by logic, there is no difference, but from maintenance perspective, it would be of great help to anyone working on the same code to identify whether it is a variable or a function based on ().

Comment: How could it ever be a variable?